# How to handle the AlarmManager after Rebooting or BOOT and cancelling the notifications on a particular date?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, bootcompleted

I am trying to show some local notifications in my android app based on certain conditions, for which I'm making use of AlarmManager and PendingIntents. Now I want to restore my local notifications after the device reboot also, for which I know I should make use of RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED but I'm confused on the implementation part. I have a doubt like wether I should should handle boot in same Receiver class that I made use of triggering Notification or I should have a separate Reciever class. Also how to cancel the notifications on a particular date.

**Manifest.xml**
'''

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**I'm calling/initiating my NotificationReciever class through PendingIntent from my Main Activity**
**And aslo enabling my BootReceiver class before setting the alarm from here using ComponentName and PackageManager** 
'''

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, NotificationReciever.class);
intent.putExtra(END_DATE, treatment.getEndDate());
intent.putExtra(MEDICINE_NAME,   treatment.getMedicineName());
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)    mCtx.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
intent.putExtra(REQUEST_CODE, req1);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mCtx, req1, intent, 0);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time1, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

**Notification Receiver** Class
'''

```
public class NotificationReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

private final String CHANNEL_ID = "personal_notifications";
public static String NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "notificationMessage";
private Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("Utils Inside NotificationReciever onReceive");
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
    this.context = context;

    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("MEDICINE_TIME");
    System.out.println("Utils medicineTime " + msg);
    int requestCode = intent.getIntExtra("REQUEST_CODE", 0);
    System.out.println("Utils requestCode  " + requestCode);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    buildNotification(context, resultIntent, msg);
}

public void buildNotification(Context context, Intent resultIntent, String msg) {
    System.out.println("Utils Inside callTheMethod");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, resultIntent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_dosage_c);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setContentTitle("It's time to take your medicine");
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContentText(msg);
    builder.setSound(soundUri);
    builder.setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 1000);
    builder.setColor(color);

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(102938, notification);
}
}
```

**BootReciever Class**
'''

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private final String CHANNEL_ID = "personal_notifications";
private Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        System.out.println("Utils Inside BootReceiver onReceive");
        this.context = context;

        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("MEDICINE_TIME");
        System.out.println("Utils medicineTime " + msg);
        int requestCode = intent.getIntExtra("REQUEST_CODE", 0);
        System.out.println("Utils requestCode  " + requestCode);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, resultIntent, 0);
        buildNotification(context, pendingIntent, msg);
    }
}

public void buildNotification(Context context, PendingIntent pendingIntent, String msg) {
    System.out.println("Utils Inside callTheMethod");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    int color = 0xffffaa00;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_dosage_c);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setContentTitle("It's time to take your medicine reboot!");
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContentText(msg);
    builder.setSound(soundUri);
    builder.setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 1000);
    builder.setColor(color);

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(102938, notification);
}
```

Comment: You should save the alarm details in a database and when the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED Broadcast is fired, start a foreground service, query your Alarm data from the database in the service, and schedule all the active alarms again..

Comment: @DarShan I'm storing my alarm details in a database. I want to know where and how I should implement RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED in my Receiver.

Comment: You have to create a new Broadcast Receiver, add permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>` in the manifest and add your Receiver in manifest with intent filter - `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Comment: @DarShan Ok. Do I need to write my complete logic again for setting alarms in the new Broadcast Reciever i.e the logic I wrote in NotificationReciver class. And where should I enable the new Broadcast Receiver?

Comment: You "enable" the `BroadcastReceiver` by adding the entries to the manifest. Android will automatically instantiate your `BroadcastReceiver` on boot and call `onReceive()`.

Comment: If the code you want to execute at boot time is similar to the code in your existing receiver, you can reuse the same class. You don't need to create a new class. In `onReceive()` you can tell if you are being called at boot time because the ACTION in the `Intent` will be `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`

Comment: @DavidWasser Thanks. I got some points. But here https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms they are making use of ComponentName and PackageManager to enable the BootReciever right? So if I make my BootReciver enabled(i.e enabled = true) in manifest there is no need to do the above process then. And which is the best way?

Comment: @DavidWasser Can you have a look at my updated code once. My BOOT_COMPLETE is not working.

Comment: @DarShan Can you have a look at my updated code once. My BOOT_COMPLETE is not working.

Comment: Is your boot receiver getting run at boot time? Remove the `android:enabled="false"` from the boot receiver and see if it is called at boot time? What device are you testing this on?

Comment: @DavidWasser Once I reboot my device my BootReceiver is getting run and showing a notification with this message "It's time to take your medicine reboot" from BootReciever setContentTitle, immediately after rebooting. But it shouldn't be that way right. It should trigger at scheduled time after rebooting.

Comment: I'm testing on Oneplus 6T

Comment: @DavidWasser I think the issue lies in 2nd block of code. For the NotificationReciver, I'm sending the requestCode and timeInterval through my pendingIntent and AlarmManager but in case of BootReciver I'm not sending any requestcode and timeInterval I think. If this is the issue, how to make data available for BootReciver also?

Comment: You can't. Your boot receiver is started by Android at boot time. If it needs additional information, you'll need to store that information in a database or `SharedPreferences` or in a file.